# Clearing failbit on stream

Tags: c++

I'm using istream::get() to read characters from a stream. The issue is that when you read the EOF character, `get` sets the failbit.

I want to keep the stream clean, because there really hasn't been an error, but I do want to keep the `eofbit` set.

How do you keep the current state of the stream, but unset the failbit. I'm having issues understanding the differences between setstate and clear and how to use them to "unset" a bit on the stream.

Comment: `get()` should set the `eofbit`, not the `failbit`.

Comment: So you want to keep the EOF bit set and just get rid of the failbit?

Comment: [std::basic_ios::clear](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) and [std::basic_ios::setstate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/setstate)

Comment: @SombreroChicken - That's what I would think too, but if you look at the documentation, it states that get() sets both the eofbit and failbit.

Comment: @SombreroChicken - Actually the docs say the version of get() will set both the eofbit and the failbit.

Comment: @NathanOliver - yes. I was surprised that get() sets the failbit when you hit EOF.

Comment: @bpeikes OK.  I've posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove a single flag some the streams state is a two part process.  First you need to get that current state of the stream with [`rdstate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdstate) and then do bitwise operations on that returned state to clear the flags you want. Then you can call [`clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) and pass the new state to that to have it set the state of the stream.  You can see all of this working with this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56da943943a5dfe3):

```
int main()
{
    std::cin.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit | std::ios_base::eofbit);

    std::cout << "before:\n";

    if (std::cin.fail()) {
        std::cout << "now cin is in fail state\n";
    }
    if (std::cin.eof()) {
        std::cout << "now cin is in eof state\n";
    }

    auto state = std::cin.rdstate();   // get state
    state &= ~std::ios_base::failbit;  // remove failbit from it
    std::cin.clear(state);             // clear old state and set new state

    std::cout << "\nafter:\n";

    if (std::cin.fail()) {
        std::cout << "now cin is in fail state\n";
    }
    if (std::cin.eof()) {
        std::cout << "now cin is in eof state\n";
    }
}
```

output:

```
before:
now cin is in fail state
now cin is in eof state

after:
now cin is in eof state
```

Comment: I'm not sure XOR is the right way to remove a bit. I believe it would be AND with the negation of the flag.

Additionally, you can set the state in the clear function. No need to use clear and setstate.

Comment: @bpeikes Good call on `clear`.   I forgot you could pass it the new state.  As as using xor goes since `std::ios_base::failbit` only has a single bit set the `xor` will make sure that only that bit gets turned off.

Comment: XOR would set the failbit if the failbit was not set though, right? XOR's table (00 -> 0), (01->1), (10->1), (11->0). I think what you need to do is && with ~std::ios_base::failbit.

Comment: @bpeikes Aha, that was what I was missing.  Answer had been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. I believe this is the correct way:

```
int main()
{
     std::cin.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit | std::ios_base::eofbit);

     // new state is current state, with failbit removed
     auto state = std::cin.rdstate() & ~std::ios_base::failbit;

     // sets all of the flags
     std::cin.clear(state);   
}
```

Comment: This does not compile. First there is a typo in `auto state = std::cin.rdstate() && ~std::io_base::failbit;` it must be `... ~std::ios_base::failbit;` with an additional **s**. Then it compiles with `error: cannot convert ‘bool’ to ‘std::ios_base::iostate’`. You should follow the [answer of NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51932785/5014688). That works.

Comment: @Ingo - Thanks for the info. I updated the code. Two typos. The ios_base one, and changing to bitwise AND instead of logical.